# Trying to run Protractor-Jasmine e2e/unit tests from cmd prompt

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, protractor

My Protractor e2e tests via a cmd prompt are running fine. However, as soon as I add a simple unit test for an AngularJS controller, the `angular-mocks` cannot be found.

I run Protractor in a Win 7 cmd prompt like this, which works great for all my E2E UI tests :

```
> node_modules\.bin\protractor conf.js
```

But once I include `sat.controller.spec.js' in my`conf.js` - 
the error is:

```
Stack:
  TypeError: module is not a function
```

my **spec.js** file shows :

```
(function(){

  describe('satController', function() {

  beforeEach(module('SATApp'));        // *** CRASHING HERE ***
    it('Should do a good job, function(){
       expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  });

}());
```

and here's my Protractor `conf.js`:

```js
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {
    directConnect: true,
    
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    framework: 'jasmine',

    specs: [
        'sat.index.spec.js',
        'sat.TopNavBar.spec.js'
        //,'sat.controller.spec.js'
        ]
};
```

FYI: My app is running on http://localhost:64174, and I've added `angular-mocks.js` to my `index.html`, but the Jasmine test does not find it.

So the main question is: Where do I refer to angular-mocks.js in order for the Jasmine unit tests to work with my angular mocks ?

I've seen specrunner.html examples, as well as jasmine.json config examples; however, I'm struggling with it.

thanks in advance...

*** **UPDATE** ***

Out of complete frustration, I took a closer look at the `Karma runner` for unit testing. Gladly (at least for now) I've managed to get a very basic unit test working with `angular-mocks.js`.

I did the following (i.e. http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/intro/configuration.html ):

1) `npm install karma`

2) `node_modules.bin\karma init'   (creates karma.conf.js by default)

3) add all of my app files to the `files:[ ]` property of the conf.js)
see this fine example: https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Testing-Article/blob/master/test/karma-shared.conf.js

4) Created my controller.spec.js file (also see  this fine example https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Testing-Article/blob/master/test/unit/controllers/controllersSpec.js )

5) from cmd prompt: `node_modules\.bin\karma start karma.conf.js`

Comment: I haven't used angular mocks in my tests before so I can't help much, but have you looked at [this documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.addMockModule)?  My guess is you would either include that in your conf.js or spec.js.  I don't think Protractor/Jasmine do anything with `.html` files

Comment: @Gunderson - Thank you. That was a great find, as `browser.addMockModule()` does indeed work. However, ideally I'd like to require the full angular-mocks.js file so I can use `inject()` as well (i.e. inject() throws an exception `inject is not defined` ). I think perhaps I need to rethink this, as completely separate my Protractor e2e tests from my jasmine unit tests and run them separately.

Comment: I think you should post as an answer because at least it did solve my initial `module is not a function` issue. Now onto the inject part.

Comment: I got a basic unit test working on an angular controller, via `Karma` (details above); however, I'm still not satisfied that I cannot figure out how to use angular-mocks.js in Protractor e2e tests.